# Why can't derived class call grandparent constructor in its initialization list?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Say I have three classes:

```
class Grandparent {
private:
    int gi;
    float gf;
public:
    Grandparent(int i1, float f1) : gi(i1), gf(f1) {}
}

class Parent : public Grandparent {
private:
    int pi;
    float pf;
public:
    Parent(int i1, float f1, int i2, float f2) : Grandparent(i1, f1), pi(i2), pf(f2) {}
}

class Child : public Parent {
private:
    int ci;
    float cf;
public:
    Child(int i1, float f1, int i2, float f2, int i3, float f3) :
        Parent(i1, f1, i2, f2), ci(i3), cf(f3) {}
}
```

Is there a way of initializing the grandparent from within the child?

I assume that if I wrote

```
Child(int i1, float f1, int i2, float f2, int i3, float f3) :
    Grandparent(i1, f1), ci(i3), cf(f3) {}
```

then it wouldn't work because nowhere have I initialized the Parent object (if this isn't why, or if there's more to it, please let me know).

However, if I think of derived classes more abstractly, such as

```
class Mammal{...}
class Dog: public Mammal{...}
class Beagle: public Dog{...}
```

then since a Beagle "is a mammal" (as opposed to a child is not necessarily a grandparent), I would assume there is a relationship between them so that one (the second derived class) should be able to communicate with the ancestor class....No?

Comment: The best you can do is tell `Parent` what you want to tell `Grandparent`. You can't know how `Parent` might need to initialize it's `Grandparent`.

Comment: You could make `Mammal` a virtual base and initialize it in `Beagle`. But it does not make sense here.

Comment: consider that inheritance is not the only way, maye its not what you actually want here. If you want `Child` to have a `Parent` and a `Grandparent` subobject and `Child` is suppoed to initialize both then you can do that with no inheritance at all.

Comment: The fact that you do not need to initialize a grandparent constructor is a blessing. With virtual inheritance you have to do this, and this is a nightmare. All you need to do know in your `Beagle` class is that it is a descendant of `Dog`, and you need to properly construct the `Dog`. The `Dog` will take care of the rest.

Comment: `Child` derives from `Parent`, which derives from `Grandparent`. In order to construct a `Child`, `Parent` must be constructed first, which requires `Grandparent` to be constructed beforehand. Base classes must be constructed before derived classes. So no, `Child` cannot construct `Grandparent` directly, that would bypass the construction of `Parent`, leaving `Parent`'s members uninitialized.